# How to add hardcoded float number values to the formula using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The folllowing VBA code doesn't work:
(I assume that addedvalue is rational numer)

```
Dim addedvalue As Double
addedvalue = 1
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & CStr(addedvalue)
```

However this one works fine:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & 1
```

Unfortunately, I must have addedvalue as a variable.

I was trying also
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & addedvalue`
but it also doesn't work.

The error message I gor is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNNS7.png)

---

**UPDATE**
The problem is why this doesn't work:

```
Sub added()
Dim rational As Double
rational = 1.1
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & rational
End Sub
```

Comment: If `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & 1` works, so will `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & addedvalue` if `addedvalue` is the number `1`.  Are you sure you are in the same cell?

Comment: And please explain what you mean by "doesn't work" - do you get an error when running the code?  Or do you just get a cell containing text such as `5+1`?

Comment: You really need to include relevant information (such as the fact that you need the `1.1` to appear as `1,1` in the localised version of the formula) within the question.  Based on the information in the question, this works.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone, using comma as a decimal separator, the VBEditor has a small "feature". Long story short, try the following:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim addedvalue As Double
    addedvalue = 1.2
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & Replace(addedvalue, ",", ".")

End Sub
```

This is my custom function, that I use for cases like this (and they are quite a lot):

```
Public Function fnStrChangeCommas(ByVal myValue As Variant) As String
    fnStrChangeCommas = Replace(CStr(myValue), ",", ".")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Viyata, this works fine, but what to do when addedvalue is not a integer?

Comment: Thanks Vitaya. It is a great solution and it works fine.

Comment: @askenazy, I am using it so much, that I have built a `changeCommas` function in my "standard" VBA library.

Comment: @askenazy - feel free to accept the answer - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Tried it and works just fine:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim addedValue As Integer
    addedValue = 1
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 & "+" & addedValue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Zipa, this works fine, but what to do when addedvalue is not an integer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a US-EN version of Excel, you have two easy options:

1. Format your number in a US-EN format prior to appending it to the formula, or
2. Write the formula in your own locale's format

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46905350/6535336) by [Vityata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5448626/vityata) gives an example of how to use option 1.

Option 2 would look something like:

```
Sub added()
    Dim rational As Double
    rational = 1.1
    ActiveCell.FormulaLocal = ActiveCell.FormulaLocal & "+" & rational
End Sub
```