# Writing a formula from VBA not working on every end-user's PC

Tags: excel, vba, locale, formula

I hope someone will be able to help me sort this one out because I've been crawling the Internet for some time now and could not find any obvious reason why the behavior of my macro under Excel works for some users (including me of course) and does not work on some other users' laptops.

**My objective:**

Write from a VBA SubRoutine a vlookup formula in one cell. Based on that vlookup, either it finds something and it displays a text A or the vlookup throws an error and it then displays a text B.

**The situation**

Here is the formula if we were writing it directly in the sheet from the end-user's perspective: `=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,DataSet2!$A$2:$A$12,1,0))),"Direct Report","Team member of direct report")`

When we copy/paste that formula on a PC where the macro fails directly in the spreadsheet. It works.
When we run the macro actually trying to incorporate that formula in that exact same cell, it fails and throws an error 400.

Here is now the VBA code attempting to write the above formula in the cell:

```
formulaString = "=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C" & CStr(counter + 2) & systemListSeparator & "DataSet2!$A$2:$A$" & CStr(2 + totalDirectReportsCount) & systemListSeparator & "1" & systemListSeparator & "0)))" & systemListSeparator & """Direct Report""" & systemListSeparator & """Team member of direct report"")"
Selection.Offset(counter, 0).Formula = formulaString
```

So the above 2 statements, as you'll have understood probably, are included in a loop and for every single row I have, I want to add that formula in the first cell from the currently selected cell.

What drives me crazy is that: it works fine on my PC, it works fine on my colleague's PC who is in Finland, but on another colleague's PC also in Finland, it does not. I have Windows 10 and Office 2016, she has Windows 10 and office 2016 as well...

So I am really wondering if there could be some regional settings or Excel settings or System Settings which could make HER Excel not interpret my "formulaString" as viable for her laptop. I have made sure to fetch the list separator to avoid those usual regional settings easy traps but would there be other similar traps I am not aware of?

Thanks a lot for any hints I could follow to progress on my investigations.
Kind regards,
Nicolas C.

Comment: is there any change in the sheets, like is any sheet hidden in your colleagues sys ?

Comment: Why are you using `systemListSeparator` there? The `Range.Formula` is **always** in en_US format, means: english function names, comma as parameter separator, dot as decimal separator. Only `Range.FormulaLocal` would be in locale format and would need to take care about system list separators and so on.

Comment: @pnuts No, I did not try ".FormulaLocal"

Comment: @NicolasC. - with `FormulaLocal` you will score own goal. Do not try it.

Comment: @AxelRichter Well, that's what I initially thought as well. I am just being careful with that and I guess it does not harm anyway, right?

Comment: If your `systemListSeparator`is something other than comma, then it will harm since `Range.Formula` needs comma as the parameter separator.

Comment: @NicolasC. - just make sure that `systemListSeparator` is set to `,` in every case and the `.Formula` should work. I suppose that it is a variable, which is getting its value from `Application.ThousandSeparator` or similar. It should not be like that.

Comment: @AxelRichter Oooooh, so what I actually thought was being careful with list separator could in the end doing the things wrong. So I should write instead: formulaString = "=IF(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C" & CStr(counter + 2) & ",DataSet2!$A$2:$A$" & CStr(2 + totalDirectReportsCount) & ",1,0))),""Direct Report"",""Team member of direct report"")" (if I have not messed in between :)). Right?

Comment: It was all said about what `Range.Formula` needs. But if I read "throws an error 400" then I don't believe that the problem comes from the formula. This error is usally thrown if VBA-References are wrong.

Comment: Yes indeed... which is why I have been struggling that much to find the root cause. Ultimately, I finally decided to catch the error and write in that cell the Err.Number and Err.Description to see what was really the error. So Excel throws 400 bluntly, but in reality, it has nothing to do with the Error 400.

Comment: @AxelRichter Can you please post an answer with your first comment because it was actually the root cause. Fetching the list separator and building up my formula that way was wrong. I've replaced my systemListSeparator variable by a simple comma and it did work. I'd be pleased to flag your answer as a solution. :)

Comment: Glad I could help you. But this is mainly the same as @Vityata has answered already. `Range.Formula` and `Range.FormulaR1C1` is working locale independent since it always expects formulas in the format of en_US locale. Maybe @Vityata could mention that yet in his answer.

Comment: @AxelRichter - check :) (feel free to edit it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a tricky point, but fortunately VBA provides an excellent solution.

Simply write the formula in Excel, select the cell and run the following code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    With ActiveCell
        Debug.Print .Formula
        Debug.Print .FormulaLocal
        Debug.Print .FormulaR1C1
    End With

End Sub
```

In German Excel, this is what you would get:

```
=SUM(C1+D1)
=SUMME(C1+D1)
=SUM(RC[2]+RC[3])
```

Then rebuild your formulas, using only `.Formula` or `.FormulaR1C1` and the result from the immediate window. Thus your colleagues from all over the world would be really happy. As noted in the 3 examples, the first and the third one always give the same answer, following the **en_US format**.

---

Another option is that Excel and VBA do not like your formula, because of the decimal separator in Finland, being different from the decimal separator in the USA. See [How to add hardcoded float number values to the formula using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905279/how-to-add-hardcoded-float-number-values-to-the-formula-using-vba/46905350#46905350) to change it a bit.

**Solution**
Nicolas C. edit: All the above comments and hereby answer have helped me solving my issue. Thank you very much guys for your prompt reaction and feedback. You really saved my day. So the root cause was indeed that I had tried to capture the end-user's system preferences on his/her locale and regional settings and making use of his/her list separator (which was ; actually) within the VBA script which was a bad move since, as mentioned by @AxelRichter and @Vityata, within a VBA script, .Formula needs always to be written in the en_US format, that is english function names, commas, etc.

I have now removed my user related list separator and replaced it with traditional commas and it solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you. I will take control of my end-user's laptop in Finland, input the formula manually in the cell and then try what you suggest to see what Excel brings. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @NicolasC. - simply write `systemListSeparator = ","` in the line before the formula and it should work.